# PHP error message: call to undefined function

Tags: php

(Disclaimer) MY php experience is approx 2 hours old and I have know idea what I am doing.

This is my error and I am wondering how do you know where the error is, for example.

as rendered in my browser, this is my error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_key_exist() in 
/home/mjcrawle/public_html/cit/home/processlogin.php on line 47
```

Line 47 is actually `if (array_key_exist('submit', $_post)){`

I do not know if the error is before or after - this is my code.

```
/*Determine if the form data was submitted*/
if (array_key_exist('submit', $_post)){
    /*this removes left over data*/
    $emailaddress = sanitize($_post['emailaddress']);
    $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

    /*verify form data*/
    $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password); 
}
```

Comment: Almost in all cases the error points to the line on where the error is, like in your case with a wrong function name. PS: variables are case sensitive, $_POST != $_post

Comment: The `array_key_exists` snippet originates in a bad tutorial. Use `isset($_POST["submit"])` or just `if ($_POST["submit"])` if you want debug information. Also I have a hunch the `sanitize()` function might not be a stellar implementation either.

Comment: @mario why is `array_key_exists` bad? The only difference is that `isset` returns false if a variable is set to null.

Comment: @meze: Entries in $_GET or $_POST are never going to contain NULL anyway. There are empty strings at best. Hence a normal boolean check is sufficient; testing for the key is overdoing it.

Comment: ⁺¹ cuz you were the first of ≈800 peoples who mistyped the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), not `array_key_exist` :).

emphasis on the latter **s**

Comment: Thanks...  Wow, Looks like I am in for a long day.

Answer (score 2):

function name is array_key_exists() (your forgot S in "exists")

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the function `array_key_exist` doesn't exist - reason for this is because you forgot to add an 's' at the end. The actual function name is `array_key_exists`.

Try this:

```
/*Determine if the form data was submitted*/
if (array_key_exists('submit', $_post)){

  /*this removes left over data*/
  $emailaddress = sanitize($_post['emailaddress']);
  $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);

  /*verify form data*/
  $auth_status = validateLogin($emailaddress, $password);
}
```